# How to invoke a method in a session bean from an Android client?

Tags: android, jsp, servlets, ejb, stateless-session-bean

I want to know whether it is possible to create an Android application to communicate with a session bean and invoke a method. if so can anybody explain how? or else can i invoke that method in the EJB with a JSP/servelet and call the JSP/Servelet with Android clients.. examples are highly appreciate

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in theory relatively simple. Servlets can be configured by `web.xml` or `@WebServlet` annotation to get executed on a certain request URL. On a HTTP GET request the `doGet()` method will be executed. On a HTTP POST request, the `doPost()` method will be executed. The business logic which the servlet executes can depend/rely on the presence of HTTP request parameters and/or the request URI pathinfo.

All you need to do is to fire a HTTP request with the right URL and/or the right request parameters and/or the right pathinfo to let the servlet execute the desired job.

The basic Java API offers the [`java.net.URL`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and [`java.net.URLConnection`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) for this. A simple HTTP GET request can be executed as follows:

```
InputStream response = new URL("http://example.com/servleturl?foo=bar&bar=foo").openStream();
// ...
```

Firing HTTP POST requests is a bit more complex. It can be done with `java.net.URLConnection` as outlined in [this mini-tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests), but Android also [ships](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) with [Apache HttpComponents Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) which allows firing and handling HTTP requests with less lines of code and more self-explaining code.

On http://androidsnippets.org you can find [a lot of examples](http://www.google.com/search?q=httpclient+site%3Aandroidsnippets.org) with `HttpClient`.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to communicate with Servelet in Android using HttpClient, HttpPost and HttpGet classes in android..